# Qt, reading XML, C++, can't seem to get the Data to be read properly

Tags: c++, xml, qt

I cannot get my Program to read the XML properly.

I have an XML file which i generated using a **Write XML** function for a program, now I am trying to write a **Read XML** function and implement it into the same program, though as a different class.

The Program has a number of data classes, all of which are used by the GUI and the **Write XML** function.
I will list the Data Classes now:
**Person.h**

```cpp
#include <QString>

class Person {

  private:
    QString m_Name;
    QString m_ContactNo;
    QString m_Email;

  public:
    Person();
    Person(QString n, QString cn, QString e = "");

    QString toString() const;

    void SetData(QString n, QString cn, QString e);

    QString getNam();
    QString getCON();
    QString getEma();

};
```

**person.cpp**

```cpp
#include "person.h"

Person::Person():m_Name(QString()), m_ContactNo(QString()), m_Email(QString()) {}

Person::Person(QString n, QString cn, QString e): m_Name(n), m_ContactNo(cn), m_Email(e) {}

QString Person::toString() const {
return "Name: " + m_Name + "\n\tContact number: " + m_ContactNo + "\n\tEmail: " + m_Email;
}

void Person::SetData(QString n, QString cn, QString e)
{
    m_Name = n;
    m_ContactNo = cn;
    m_Email = e;
}

QString Person::getNam()
{
    return m_Name;
}

QString Person::getCON()
{
    return m_ContactNo;
}

QString Person::getEma()
{
    return m_Email;
}
```

**Booking.h**

```cpp
#include <QDate>
#include "person.h"

class Booking {
  private:

    Person m_Contact;
    QDate m_ArrivalDate;
    QDate m_DepartureDate;
    bool sha = false;

    Person m_Guest1;
    Person m_Guest2;
protected:

    const double SINGLE_PPPN;
    const double SHARING_PPPN;

  public:

    Booking(Person c, QDate a, QDate d);

    virtual ~Booking();

    bool booked(QDate d) const;

    virtual QString toString() const;
    virtual double rate() const = 0;

    void setSHA(bool tf);
    bool getsha();

    Person getCon();
    QDate getArr();
    QDate getDep();

    void setGuest1(Person g);
    void setGuest2(Person g);

    Person getGuest1();
    Person getGuest2();
};
```

**Booking.cpp**

```cpp
#include "booking.h"

Booking::Booking(Person c, QDate a, QDate d): m_Contact(c), m_ArrivalDate(a), m_DepartureDate(d),SINGLE_PPPN(300),SHARING_PPPN(500) {
}

Booking::~Booking(){}

bool Booking::booked(QDate d) const{
    return d >= m_ArrivalDate && d < m_DepartureDate;
}

QString Booking::toString() const {
    return "Contact: " + m_Contact.toString() + "\nDate of arrival: " +
    m_ArrivalDate.toString() + "\nDate of departure: " +
    m_DepartureDate.toString();
}

void Booking::setSHA(bool tf)
{
    sha = tf;
}

bool Booking::getsha()
{
    return sha;
}

Person Booking::getCon()
{
    return m_Contact;
}
QDate Booking::getArr()
{
    return m_ArrivalDate;
}

QDate Booking::getDep()
{
    return m_DepartureDate;
}

void Booking::setGuest1(Person g)
{
    m_Guest1 = g;
}
void Booking::setGuest2(Person g)
{
    m_Guest2 = g;
}

Person Booking::getGuest1()
{
    return m_Guest1;
}
Person Booking::getGuest2()
{
    return m_Guest2;
}
```

**bookinglist.h**

```cpp
#include <QList>
#include "booking.h"

class BookingList {

  public:

    BookingList();

    ~BookingList();

    int roomsAvailable(QDate d) const;

    bool vacancy(QDate a, QDate d) const;

    bool addBooking(Person c, QDate a, QDate d, Person* g1, Person* g2 = NULL);
    QString toString() const;

    QList<Booking*> getList();

private:
   QList<Booking*> listBooking;
   const int NO_OF_ROOMS;
};
```

**bookinglist.cpp**

```cpp
#include "bookinglist.h"
#include "sharing.h"
#include "single.h"


BookingList::BookingList():NO_OF_ROOMS(5){}


BookingList::~BookingList(){
    qDeleteAll(listBooking);
    listBooking.clear();
}

//checks and returns the number of rooms of available for a given date
int BookingList::roomsAvailable(QDate d) const {
    int result = NO_OF_ROOMS;
    foreach (Booking * b, listBooking) {
        if (b->booked(d)) {
            result--;
        }
    }
    return result;
}

//checks and returns whether there is room available in a given period
bool BookingList::vacancy(QDate a, QDate d) const {
    if (a.isValid() && d.isValid() && a < d) {
        for (QDate i = a; i < d; i = i.addDays(1)) {
            if (roomsAvailable(i) <= 0) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

//creates a booking instance if there is vacancy
bool BookingList::addBooking(Person c, QDate a, QDate d, Person* g1, Person*g2) {
    Booking* b = NULL;
    if(vacancy(a,d) == true){
        if (g2 == NULL) {
            b = new Single(c, a, d, *g1);
            b->setSHA(false);
        } else {
            b = new Sharing(c, a, d, *g1, *g2);
            b->setSHA(true);
        }
        listBooking.append(b);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}


QString BookingList::toString() const{
    QString result;
    foreach (Booking * b, listBooking) {
        result.append(b->toString());
        result.append("\n");
        result.append("-------------------------------");
        result.append("\n");
    }
    return result;
}


QList<Booking*> BookingList::getList()
{
    return listBooking;
}
```

**sharing.h**

```cpp
#include "booking.h"
#include "person.h"

class Sharing : public Booking {

  private:
    //data members
    Person m_Guest1;
    Person m_Guest2;

  public:
    
    Sharing(Person c, QDate a, QDate d, Person g1, Person g2);

    QString toString() const;

    double rate() const;

    void set_Guest1();
    void set_Guest2();
};
```

**sharing.cpp**

```cpp
#include "sharing.h"

Sharing::Sharing(Person c, QDate a, QDate d, Person g1, Person g2): Booking(c, a, d), m_Guest1(g1), m_Guest2(g2)
{
    set_Guest1();
    set_Guest2();
}

QString Sharing::toString() const {
    return Booking::toString() + "\nGuest 1: " + m_Guest1.toString() +"\nGuest 2: "
    + m_Guest2.toString();
}

double Sharing::rate()const{
    return 2 * Booking::SHARING_PPPN;
}


void Sharing::set_Guest1()
{
    setGuest1(m_Guest1);
}
void Sharing::set_Guest2()
{
    setGuest2(m_Guest2);
}
```

**single.h**

```cpp
#include "booking.h"
#include "person.h"

class Single : public Booking
{

  private:
    //data member
    Person m_Guest;

  public:

    Single(Person c, QDate a, QDate d, Person g);

    QString toString() const;

    double rate() const;

    void set_Guest();
};
```

**single.cpp**

```cpp
#include "single.h"

Single::Single(Person c, QDate a, QDate d, Person g): Booking(c, a, d), m_Guest(g)
{
    set_Guest();
}

QString Single::toString() const {
    return Booking::toString() + "\nGuest: " + m_Guest.toString();
}

double Single::rate() const{
    return Booking::SINGLE_PPPN;
}

void Single::set_Guest()
{
    setGuest1(m_Guest);
}
```

These are the Data Classes I use.  Here is the XML File I created:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<bookinglist>
 <Sharing type="sharing">
  <Contact Email="Bill@gmail.com" Contact_No="123911" Name="Bill"/>
  <Arrivaldate>2020-01-01</Arrivaldate>
  <Departdate>2020-01-04</Departdate>
  <Guest1 Email="Bill@gmail.com" Contact_No="123911" Name="Bill"/>
  <Guest2 Email="jj@hotmail.com" Contact_No="321119" Name="JJ"/>
 </Sharing>
 <Sharing type="single">
  <Contact Email="Bill@gmail.com" Contact_No="123911" Name="Bill"/>
  <Arrivaldate>2020-01-01</Arrivaldate>
  <Departdate>2020-01-04</Departdate>
  <Guest1 Email="J@gmail.com" Contact_No="987311" Name="John"/>
 </Sharing>
</bookinglist>
```

And here is the **Read XML** class
**readxml.h**

```cpp
#include "bookinglist.h"

class ReadXML
{
public:
    ReadXML();

    void Read_XML();

    QList<Booking*> LB();

private:
    BookingList BL;
};
```

**readxml.cpp**

```cpp
#include "readxml.h"

#include <QFile>
#include <QtXml>
#include <QRegularExpression>

void makeBooking(BookingList & bl, Person c, QDate a, QDate d, Person* g1,Person* g2 = NULL) {
        bool result = bl.addBooking(c, a, d, g1, g2);
        if(result==false){
            qDebug() << "**Booking unsuccessful (no vacancies or length of stay is 0)**";
        }
        else{
            qDebug() << "**Booking successful**";
        }
}

ReadXML::ReadXML()
{
}

void ReadXML::Read_XML()
{
    QString Filter = "All File (*.*) ;; XML File (*.xml)";
    QString File_Open_Location = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this,"Open File","C://",Filter);
    QDomDocument doc;
    QFile file(File_Open_Location);

    doc.setContent(&file);
    if(!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly|QIODevice::Text))
    {
        qDebug()<<"Failed to open the file";
    } else
    {
        if(!doc.setContent(&file))
        {
            qDebug() <<"Failed to load File";
        }
        file.close();
    }
    QDomElement root = doc.documentElement();
    if(root.tagName() == "bookinglist")
    {
        QDomElement ShaType = root.firstChildElement();
        if(ShaType.tagName() == "Sharing")
        {
            QString CType;
            CType = ShaType.attribute("type");
            if(CType == "sharing")
            {
                QDomElement Contact = ShaType.firstChildElement();
                QString CName, CConNo, CEma;
                QString G1Name, G1ConNo, G1Ema;
                QString G2Name, G2ConNo, G2Ema;

                QDate ArrDate, DepDate;

                CName = Contact.attribute("Name");
                CConNo = Contact.attribute("Contact_No");
                CEma = Contact.attribute("Email");
                Person C = Person(CName, CConNo, CEma);

                QDomElement ADate = Contact.nextSiblingElement();

                QString arriveD = ADate.text();
                ArrDate = QDate::fromString(arriveD,"yyyy-MM-dd");

                QDomElement DDate = Contact.nextSiblingElement();

                QString departD = DDate.text();
                DepDate = QDate::fromString(departD,"yyyy-MM-dd");

                QDomElement Guest_1 = Contact.nextSiblingElement();
                G1Name = Guest_1.attribute("Name");
                G1ConNo = Guest_1.attribute("Contact_No");
                G1Ema = Guest_1.attribute("Email");

                Person G1 = Person(G1Name, G1ConNo, G1Ema);

                QDomElement Guest_2 = Contact.nextSiblingElement();
                G2Name = Guest_2.attribute("Name");
                G2ConNo = Guest_2.attribute("Contact_No");
                G2Ema = Guest_2.attribute("Email");

                Person G2 = Person(G2Name, G2ConNo, G2Ema);


                makeBooking(BL,C, ArrDate, DepDate, &G1, &G2);
            } else if(CType == "single")
            {
                QDomElement Contact = ShaType.firstChildElement();
                QString CName, CConNo, CEma;
                QString G1Name, G1ConNo, G1Ema;

                QDate ArrDate, DepDate;

                CName = Contact.attribute("Name");
                CConNo = Contact.attribute("Contact_No");
                CEma = Contact.attribute("Email");
                Person C = Person(CName, CConNo, CEma);

                QDomElement ADate = Contact.nextSiblingElement();

                QString arriveD = ADate.text();
                ArrDate = QDate::fromString(arriveD,"yyyy-MM-dd");

                QDomElement DDate = Contact.nextSiblingElement();

                QString departD = DDate.text();
                DepDate = QDate::fromString(departD,"yyyy-MM-dd");

                QDomElement Guest_1 = Contact.nextSiblingElement();
                G1Name = Guest_1.attribute("Name");
                G1ConNo = Guest_1.attribute("Contact_No");
                G1Ema = Guest_1.attribute("Email");

                Person G1 = Person(G1Name, G1ConNo, G1Ema);
                makeBooking(BL, C, ArrDate, DepDate, &G1);
            }

        }
        ShaType = ShaType.nextSiblingElement();
    }
    qDebug() << "YESSIRR";
    file.close();
}

QList<Booking *> ReadXML::LB()
{
    return BL.getList();
}
```

Note: I forgot to implement a nestled loop inside **readxml.cpp** so it loops the **ShaType**

When I run the script, I get a qDebug message from the **makeBooking** function in **readxml.cpp** telling me that the Booking was not successful.  Any help?

Comment: Did you try stepping through your code with a debugger to find out why the function is failing?

Comment: From reading your code (I didn't test it), `Contact.nextSiblingElement()` will always return the same element, therefore `BookingList::vacancy` will have two equal parameters and will return false. Use either `Contact.nextSiblingElement("Arrivaldate")` / `Contact.nextSiblingElement("Departdate")` or `Contact.nextSiblingElement()` / `ADate.nextSiblingElement()`. I personally would prefer the first, since it allows more flexibility in the order of the xml nodes. See https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qdomnode.html#nextSiblingElement for the details.

Comment: @absolute.madness Thanks. Your suggestion worked. It is working now.